# All devices using hdpi xml files

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have two devices of hdpi and xxhdpi screen density. All of my xml files are in the 'layout' folder. Since the hdpi device's screen is small, I copied some xml files to 'layout-hdpi' folder and made the respective changes for the hdpi device. The problem is that the changes I made for the hdpi device are getting reflected even on my xxhdpi device.
What can be the problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: make sure you are not changing files in `layout` folder

Comment: I'm not sure but probably Android is using `hdpi` directory for screens larger or equal to `hdpi` so it includes `xxhdpi` as well. And default layout directory is used for smaller screens. To check it try to create a `xhdpi` directory and copy default layout to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the hdpi device's screen is small, I copied some xml files to 'layout-hdpi' folder

Screen size is not related to screen density. Do not create `layout` directories based on density. Create `layout` directories based on screen size (e.g., `layout-sw640dp` for layout resources to be used on devices whose smallest width is 4" or larger).

Comment: I can't see anything related to screen size in the question. It is all about density

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: The second sentence begins with "Since the hdpi device's screen is small". I have adjusted my answer to quote the relevant material.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I used introspect app to get the density of my devices. So I targeted my hdpi device using layout-hdpi folder. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @IshankGupta: You are using `layout-hdpi`. Stop using `layout-hdpi`. Use a layout resource directory **based on screen size** if you want to have different layouts based on screen size.

Comment: I made two layout folders named 'layout-w424dp-h753dp' and 'layout-w320dp-h533dp'. But on my prior device, layouts of the later device are being used. Also tried using 'layout-sw320dp' folder but I faced the same problem.

Comment: @IshankGupta: The values of the sizes are minimums. So, `layout-sw320dp` says "use this directory on devices with a smallest width of 2" **or greater**". You put your smallest layouts in `res/layout/`, and in those cases where you need a different layout for larger screens, you create a directory to be used on those larger screens. In general, you should not need very many of these; your layout resources themselves should be flexible (e.g., few concrete dimensions).

Comment: @IshankGupta: Having something like `res/layout-w424dp-h753dp/` is not a scalable solution. There are ~10,000 Android device models, and I would estimate that there are well over 100 different screen resolutions. You will find it very difficult to manage 100+ `res/layout.../` directories. Just as Web designers try to use flexible CSS rules and limit the number of distinct media queries, Android developers need to use flexible layouts and try to limit the number of distinct resource directories.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare and everyone for the help. I reworked all my screens so that they scale nicely for most of the screen sizes.